# Get object name when object tab is override by vf page

Tags: visualforce, dynamic-visualforce, salesforce-classic

I'm thinking to write a dynamic vf page which will override the object Tab(Account). So how to know the object name in apex class.
Once I got the object name then I will then i will perform remaining tasks.

```
<apex:page controller="controllerOverrideTab" showHeader="true" standardStylesheets="true" 
       sidebar="true" applyHtmlTag="true" applyBodyTag="true" docType="html-5.0" >
 <h1>
---custom code
    </h1>  
</apex:page>
```

not using standardController. I need to override the Account's or opportunity's tab page. so I'm thinking to use dynamic vf page and controller.

Answer (score 1):

You can determine the object from the StandardController.

```
public MyPageController(ApexPages.StandardController controller) {
  SobjectType objType = controller.getRecord().getSobjectType();
  // You can describe using the objType object to get object and field information
}
```

Read more about it in the [StandardController](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/apex_pages_standardcontroller.htm) and [sObjecctType](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_class_Schema_SObjectType.htm#!) class, as well as the related describe calls.